# iOS - Unknown class PFImageView

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Getting this error when trying to include a PFImageView in interface builder (using Parse and ParseUI in my project).  I know other people have had this issue but it seems the only reliable solution is to include `[PFImageView class];` in the app delegate and I'm using Swift so I'm not sure how to translate this solution.  I've tried restarting XCode, using the simulator instead of the phone, cleaning the project, nothing gets it working.

Comment: have you tried bridging the header file?

Comment: Which header file are you referring to?  The ParseUI header or a custom one where I include that Obj C code?  The former doesn't seem to make a difference, and the latter..not sure how to set up that code in a header... `#ifndef Kollective_PFImageView_h
#define Kollective_PFImageView_h

[PFImageView class];

#endif
` doesn't work

Comment: Looking into using cocoapods to help manage dependencies. It is easy to drop into your existing project and will save you tons of time in the future for updating existing frameworks/SDKs